# Парсинг сайта на selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
div_link = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "image")
for value in div_link:

    link.append(div_link.__getattribute__("src"))
    print(link)
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'src'

Comment: Ответ в ошибке есть

Comment: и, пожалуйста, добавляйте исходный текст (html, в данном случае), в части случаев приходится программировать для проверки и поиска ошибок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
div_link = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "image")
for value in div_link:
    link.append(value.get_attribute("src"))
    print(link)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1503831/edit)».